# Nginx - root folder

Tags: nginx

When I am accesing page at http://myIP I am seeing files in folder

```
var/www/html
```

instead of

```
var/www/html/src/public
```

I have set up following setting in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
root /var/www/html/src/public;
index index.html index.htm;
```

and also restarted nginx.

What could be wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Either you forgot to restart the http daemon or there is another root defined inside the configuration. Strictly speaking this could also be a synbolic link or mount and you might have to clear your browser cache. But more likely it is one of the first two.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I am using Digital ocean. How can I restart http deamon?

Comment: If I try myIP:8888 (as I have this port defined in config), I get 403 Forbidden.

Comment: I have no idea about "Digital ocean". You said you use nginx, that _is_ the http daemon. Just restart it. And I don't understand your remark about a request to port 8888. In the question you said you see files of some wolder when making a request. Now you say you get http 403. So what is true?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your document root in:

> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Or define it in your virtual host config file in:

> /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

Here is an example default.conf file setup:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443 ssl;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    server_name  adamsawesomewebsite.tk;
    root   /var/www/vhosts/adamsawesomewebsite.tk/httpdocs;
    index  index.php index.html;
    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
    #
    #error_page  404              /404.html;
    #location = /40x.html {
    #}
    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
    }
    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```